# MVC5 DateTime field not call json on HTTPGET and not passed data on EditView to field

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5

I have Birth Day field which check on Json if date is on the past.
it's working only for Edit not for Create
On Edit View- the data not passed to his field
My class include :

I have class:

```
[Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]        
        [Remote("ValidateBirthDate","Student")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DisplayName("Date Of Birth")]
        public  DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Create & Edit View: on Edit-the data not pass to the field

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Json on control:

```
//for Create
    [HttpGet]
            public JsonResult ValidateBirthDate(DateTime DateOfBirth)
            {
                int date = DateTime.Compare(DateOfBirth, DateTime.Today);

                if(date>=0)
                {
                    return Json("Please enter a valid date in the past", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                return Json(true,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

and for [HTTPPOST] -working fine:

```
//for Edit
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("ValidateBirthDate")]
    public JsonResult ValidateBirthDatePost(DateTime DateOfBirth)
    {....}
```

Why the data not passed to his field on Edit View?
Why its not response to Create too? What I miss?
(I try avoid datepicker..)

**Solved** by replacing:

```
 public  **string** DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1- Code to check the date value (HttpPost)

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ValidateBirthDate(DateTime DateOfBirth)
{
    int date = DateTime.Compare(DateOfBirth, DateTime.Today);

    if(date>=0)
    {
        return Json("Please enter a valid date in the past", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json(true,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

2- Html code

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
```

Comment: This is what I do, you can see on my code  (by adding [ActionName("ValidateBirthDate")]
)